# Ruby If statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am trying to do a post and run some if statement. What I want to do is:

1. check all fields are filled
2. if all fields are filled move on to next step, or else reload page
3. check if already in data base
4. add if not already in data base

```
post "/movies/new" do
  title = params[:title]
  year = params[:year]
  gross = params[:gross]
  poster = params[:poster]
  trailer = params[:trailer]

  if title && year && gross && poster && trailer
      movie = Movie.find_by(title: title, year: year, gross: gross)
    if movie
      redirect "/movies/#{movie.id}"
    else
      movie = Movie.new(title: title, year: year, gross: gross, poster: poster, trailer: trailer)
      if movie.save
        redirect "/movies/#{movie.id}"
      else
        erb :'movies/new'
      end
    end
  else
   erb :'movies/new'
  end
end
```

I don't think my if statement is correct. It works even if all my fields are not filled

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I don't think my if statement is correct. It works even if all my fields are not filled

Comment: There's too little information to answer your question.

Comment: Try to test what exactly is in `title`, `year` etc. Remember that ruby will tream anything except `nil` and `false` as true, even empty string or 0.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will look into it

Comment: @AndyLi if you are using Sinatra, please state that clearly in the question. Else, please tell us what framework you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you type nothing in the HTML fields, they will still be submitted as empty strings.

You can avoid having empty parameters by, for example, filtering them:

```
post '/movies/new' do
  params.reject! { |key, value| value.empty? }
  # rest of your code
end
```

Also I would rather post to `/movies` rather than to `/movies/new`, that's more REST-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing a lot of work in one single method. I would suggest to restructure it into smaller chunks to make it easier to manage. I mostly code for Rails, so apologies if parts of these do not apply to your framework.

```
post "/movies/new" do
  movie = find_movie || create_movie

  if movie
    redirect "/movies/#{movie.id}"
  else
    erb :'movies/new'
  end
end

def find_movie
  # guard condition to ensure that the required parameters are there
  required_params = [:title, :year, :gross]
  return nil unless params_present?(required_params)

  Movie.find_by(params_from_keys(required_params))
end

def create_movie
  required_params = [:title, :year, :gross, :poster, :trailer]
  return nil unless params_present?(required_params)  

  movie = Movie.new(params_from_keys(required_params))
  movie.save ? movie : nil # only return the movie if it is successfully saved
end

# utility method to check whether all provided params are present
def params_present?(keys) 
  keys.each {|key| return false if params[key].blank? }
  true
end

# utility method to convert params into the hash format required to create / find a record
def params_from_keys(keys)
  paras = {}
  keys.each { |key| paras.merge!(key: params[key]) }
  paras
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if` condition to check fields are blank like below -

```
unless [title, year, gross, poster, trailer].any?(&:blank?)
```

This will check any of the field should not be `nil` or blank(`""`).